# Failing hidden CodeFights test - can't find flaw in code

Tags: python, python-2.7

Here's the challenge I'm failing a hidden test on:

> Given integers n, l and r, find the number of ways to represent n as a sum of two integers A and B such that l ≤ A ≤ B ≤ r.

Here's my code:

```
def countSumOfTwoRepresentations2(n, l, r):
    #initializing return variable
    totalcount = 0
    #returns 0 in impossible cases
    if (l + r > n):
        return 0
    if (r + r < n):
        return 0
    if (r < (n/2)) or (l > (n/2)):
        return 0
    # finding the total number of possibilities
    p = n / 2
    # finding which if l or r is further from 0 or n, respectively
    c = max((n-r),l)
    # removing impossible cases
    totalcount = (p - c) + 1
    return totalcount
```

It passes all the tests I can see the inputs for (and every custom one I could think of), but fails on one of the hidden ones. Any obvious flaws I'm missing? Thanks

Comment: If this indeed is Python, then yes, I can spot the flaw. Your indentation is *way* off.

Comment: `if (l + r > n):` - how is that an impossible case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As user2357112 noted, you have rejected some valid cases, such as 11, 5, 9: that still permits 6+5 as a solution.

You have also failed to reject an invalid case due to integer division, such as 11, 2, 5, where n == 2*r + 1; however, in these cases, your calculations naturally return 0.
*I'm wrong here: **r + r < n** will catch this case, but this means that your r < (n/2) case is redundant*

If you still have trouble with your testing, please include your test classes and test vectors (input sets).